# Import es6 module in repl

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules, babel-node, babel-cli

I wrote an es6 module that I'm transpiling with Babel.js and packaging with Webpack. I would like to be able to load this module into a repl so that I can use it there, so I installed `babel-cli` to get `babel-node`. I saw the notice saying that "ES6-style module-loading may not function as expected," so I wasn't surprised by this:

```
> import Point from './js/model/Point'
SyntaxError: repl: Modules aren't supported in the REPL
> 1 | import Point from './js/model/Point'
    | ^
```

But I was surprised by this:

```
> var Point = require('./js/model/Point')
/Users/brianmc7/workspace/tetris-crush/js/model/Point.js:2
export default class Point {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

What gives? Doesn't `babel-node` transpile files when I require them in the repl? Is there a JavaScript repl that does, or some easy workaround? Webpack compiles my project just fine, so I know there are no syntax errors.

Comment: Can you show your .babelrc and the command/script you're using to traspile?

Comment: @Goliadkin Haha, thanks, didn't have one. All my configuration was in `webpack.config.js`, and Babel didn't know to look there when I ran it outside of webpack. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that just having your babel configuration in your `webpack.config.js` doesn't work for `babel-node` (obvious in retrospect). [Goliadkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3916621/goliadkin)'s comment on my question lead me to create a `.babelrc`, which fixed my problem. This minimal configuration was all I needed:

```
{
    presets: ['es2015']
}
```

Comment: @Goliadkin Would love to, but I have to wait two days to accept my own answer. Thanks again for the help, though!

Comment: Just to clarify, you were able to get `require` to work in the REPL but not `import`? From what I can tell, [import is not possible](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1264#issuecomment-93230455)

Comment: @Marklar Correct.